# How here private data members are accessed from the class instance (c++,oops,operator overloading)

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++17, operator-overloading

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex {
private:
    int real, imag;
public:
    Complex(int r = 0, int i = 0) {real = r; imag = i;}
    
    // This is automatically called when '+' is used with
    // between two Complex objects
    Complex operator + (Complex const &obj) {
        Complex res;
        res.real = real + obj.real;
        res.imag = imag + obj.imag;
        return res;
    }
    void print() { cout << real << " + i" << imag << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
    Complex c1(10, 5), c2(2, 4);
    Complex c3 = c1 + c2;
    c3.print();
}
```

Here operator + is overloaded and it is accesing the private member of res class

Some more examples are
ex1 -

```
struct Edge {
    int a,b,w;
};
bool operator<(const Edge& x, const Edge& y) { return x.w < y.w; }
```

ex2-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct Edge {
    int a,b,w;
    bool operator<(const Edge& y) { return w < y.w; }
};

int main() {
    int M = 4;
    vector<Edge> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
        int a,b,w; cin >> a >> b >> w;
        v.push_back({a,b,w});
    }
    sort(begin(v),end(v));
    for (Edge e: v) cout << e.a << " " << e.b << " " << e.w << "\n";
}
```

ex1 and ex2 are from the usaco.guide and the first example was from the geeks for geeks

Can anyone explain how it works ?

Comment: What exactly is your question? How `operator+` can access private members? It is a member function, it has access to it.

Comment: If a class couldn't access **its own** private members, then such private members wouldn't be much use, would they?

Comment: And, in your Ex1 & Ex2 cases, the `Edge` `struct` doesn't have any private members. That's one of the very few differences between `struct` and `class` - default access attributes.

Comment: The `operator+()` you have defined in your first example is a member function of the class so has access to all (`private`, `protected`, and `public`) members of that class.   In "ex1", `Edge` is a `struct` type, so its members are `public` by default which means they can be accessed by any code (including the `operator<()` which is not a member of that class).   In "ex2", `Edge` is a `struct` type (so its members are accessible by anything) AND the `operator<()` is a member function of `Edge`.

Comment: Are you not equally surprised that it also accesses the private members of the parameter `obj`?

Comment: Typically for geeksforgeeks, it's not a very good example - a less inexperienced C++ programmer than the author would write `return Complex(real + obj.real, imag + obj.imag);`, and use an initializer list for the constructor. That site has a pretty bad reputation and it's barely (if at all) worth what you're paying for it. Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Answer (score 0):

> How here private data members are accessed from the class instance. Can anyone explain how it works ?

First things first, in ex1 and ex2 you're using a `struct` and so by default every member is `public`. So any user of the class has access to its members.

Now, **even if** those data members were `private`, you've overloaded `operator+` and `operator<` as member functions. And a member function has full access to any(`private`, `public` or `protected`) member of the corresponding class type.